# How to remove items from the keyboard list in Visual Studio's options dialogue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dotcover

I have just uninstalled Jetbrain's dotCover 2.7 but it has left all its keyboard items in Visual Studio's (VS2013) options dialogue:

[image]

How do I get rid of these?

Answer (score 0):

Go to TOOLS menu and select 'Import and Export Settings'. There you can reset all your Visual Studio settings to the default settings.

Comment: Nope that didn't work although my current settings directory is %LOCALAPPDATA%\jetbrains\dotcover\v2.7\vs12.0

Answer (score 0):

Quit vs, then from a developer command prompt, do:

```
devenv /updateconfiguration
```

and open Visual studio and see if they are still there.  If that doesn't work, do:

```
devenv /setup
```

and see if that works.  ideally updateconfiguration should do it, but /setup might be reqired depending on how they installed stuff...